# Autohotkey: task to copy from browser and paste on text editor

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to build a script that uses both a browser and a texteditor. The workflow I can summarize as follows:

1. Right click on a video for streaming
2. Click on the option to copy the redirection link
3. Switch to a text editor (Slickedit in my case)
4. Paste the copied link
5. Go back to the browser and await next command.

I want to automate this with a single key press while I am standing on the link with the mouse. This has been
my attempt:

```
^+!a::
    Click Right, 392, 64     ;execute in browser
    Click Left, 410, 79      ;
    Send, !{Tab}             ;switch to text editor
    Send, ^V                 ;paste in text editor
    Send, !{Tab}             ;switch back to browser
return
```

The script isn't working correctly because it appears not to be executing the ^V command.
I suspect it's because it is executing it before Slickedit is even active.  How can I syncronize
these KeyPreses so that they are executed at the right times? Also is there a nicer way for me to
switch to Slickedit without relying on the alt-tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you could use to make your script better. [WinActivate](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm), [clipboard](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm), and improved mouse movement seem to be good ones to add.

```
^+!a::
    clipboard =                  ; clears clipboard
    Click Right                  ; execute in browser
    MouseMove, 18, 15, 50, R     ; Moves mouse relative to start location
    Click Left     
    ClipWait, 2                  ; Waits 2 seconds for clipboard to contain something
    WinActivate, Slickedit       ; Switch to text editor
    WinWaitActive, Slickedit
    Send % clipboard             ; paste in text editor
    WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; or your browser of choice
Return
```

Use the included Window Spy to find the correct Window titles or classes to be used in the `WinActivate` commands.

Comment: I'll try this out when I get home. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to improve this line: Send % clipboard ?
It is kind of slow when I run it, as it copies what is on the clipboard letter by letter.

Comment: You could revert to your previous code by using `Send, ^V`.  This will use the built in paste function instead of `Send` which does in fact send character by character.

Comment: `SendInput` would probably help.